# coroutine unity - unpredictable behavior

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

Anybody can explain the problem of my code?

I start two coroutines at the beginning of the program. These are:

```
loader = StartCoroutine(loadobjectsfromfile);
buffer = StartCoroutine(setBufferToSpesificLocation(0));
```

To explain briefly
loadobjectsfromfile reads obj from file and adds them to `List<GameObjects> loadedObject`. Ant It reads more until the buffer is full.

```
 IEnumerator loadobjectsfromfile(string filepath, List<GameObject> objs)
    {       while(...)
            {
                // other code lines
               // ...
                loadedObject.Add(gam);
                while (full_)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }  
                k++;
                yield return null;
            } }
```

setBufferTheSpesificLocation adds the objecst from list to buffer[] array. And it also puts objects until the buffer is full.

```
 IEnumerator setBufferToSpesificLocation(int startPoint)
    {

        for ( foo = startPoint; foo < loadedObject.Count; foo++)
        {

            while (full_)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            put(loadedObject[foo]);

            yield return null;
        }

    }

 void put(GameObject frame)
    {

        buff_[head_] = frame;
        head_ = (head_ + 1) % bufferSize;
        full_ = head_ == tail_;


    }
```

And the last part, how do we empty the buffer? I call other coroutine called by display.

```
IEnumerator displayMesh(GameObject[] objs)
    {


        while (!empty())
        {
            // other lines
            full_ = false; // have a free space
        }

    }
```

well, If i start first two coroutine and after that call last coroutine( there is no problem. My code is working well.  But i have a problem with a new case.

```
loader = StartCoroutine(loadobjectsfromfile);
buffer = StartCoroutine(setBufferToSpesificLocation(0));
StopCoroutine(buffer);
buffer = StartCoroutine(setBufferToSpesificLocation(50)); // 
play = StartCoroutine(displayMesh(buff_));
```

Problem is, loader doesnt work in this case after call second buffer coroutine. When  "`( foo = startPoint; foo < loadedObject.Count; foo++)`" ends then loader is working.

I dont get it. I think, If `full_` is false,  both of loader and buffer have to work but only buffer is working, and loader is waiting "buffer for{} loop"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to start a coroutine and then stop it immediately. When you call StartCoroutine it will run the routine until it reaches a yield. After running the routine to the first yield it will run the next line where the coroutine was started.

check this link about Order of Execution for Event Functions:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html#Coroutines

and this one about Coroutines
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity3.html

So in your case, the things will happen in this order:

1: StartCoroutine

```
loader = StartCoroutine(loadobjectsfromfile);
```

2: Run to the first yield

```
 IEnumerator loadobjectsfromfile(string filepath, List<GameObject> objs)
    {       while(...)
            {
                // other code lines
               // ...
                loadedObject.Add(gam);
                while (full_)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }  
                k++;
                yield return null; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            } }
```

3: Start the next coroutine

```
buffer = StartCoroutine(setBufferToSpesificLocation(0));
```

4: Run to the first yield

```
 IEnumerator setBufferToSpesificLocation(int startPoint)
    {

        for ( foo = startPoint; foo < loadedObject.Count; foo++)
        {

            while (full_)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            put(loadedObject[foo]);

            yield return null; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }

    }
```

4: Stop the buffer routine

```
StopCoroutine(buffer);
```

5: Start again the buffer but now with startPoint param set to 50

```
buffer = StartCoroutine(setBufferToSpesificLocation(50));
```

6: Run to the first yield??? No, foo = startPoint which is now 50...

```
IEnumerator setBufferToSpesificLocation(int startPoint)
    {
        //it will skip the loop as foo is 50 and loadedObject.Count is 1 (probabbly)
        for ( foo = startPoint; foo < loadedObject.Count; foo++) 
        {
            //code...
        }

        //WILL END THE COROUTINE
    }
```

Comment: i want just skip some objects, dont add them to my buffer. in my second case, 
loadedObject.Count = 200
buffer= [50...149] (setted 50)
now  at this moments full_ = 1, so buffer and loader dont work. and after one step full_ ll be  0 because of displayMesh coroutine.
new buffer=[51...149] and full_ is 1 again(circular).
well thats my question, buffer works when the full_  is 0 but my loader doesnt work. and my loaderObjects.Count is still 200. It must be 201 and then 202 bla bla.